# How to stop a jQuery animation when it is executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This is my sample code. Below I explain my problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min-1.10.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.animate-colors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
  $("a").mouseover(function (){
        $("a").animate({color: "#eee"});
   });

 $("a").mouseleave(function () {
        $('a').animate({color: '#000'});
  });
});
</script>
<a href="javascript:;">Hover Me</a>
```

Explanation:

When I hover over an item once this is executed consecutively every time you pass the mouse and I would like not to run again while doing an action. What I can recommend for this?

Comment: I'd use a flag true/false set on first execution.

Comment: So you'd like to stop the animation or make the animation only happen once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, chain your events and use `on`, next add `.stop(stop, stop)`:

```
$(function () {
  $("a").on('mouseover', function (){
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({color: "#eee"});
   }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({color: '#000'});
   });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/bktUt/

Comment: @FrancisGoris No problem :-D Happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

please use some logical thing:

Declare a variable in $(document).ready function.

```
var i = 0;

var j = 0;

 $(function () {
    if(i==0){
      i=1;
      $("a").mouseover(function (){
        $("a").animate({color: "#eee"});
      });

     }
    if(j==0){
       j=1;
       $("a").mouseleave(function () {
        $('a').animate({color: '#000'});
     }); 
    }
 });
 }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu are using the correct exit event of mouseleave, but you are not using the correct enter event. You should be using mouseenter which does not fire multiple times.

> **[.mouseenter( handler(eventObject) )](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)**
>
> **Description:** Bind an event handler to be fired when the mouse enters
>   an element, or trigger that handler on an element.

Also as Neal pointed out, you should also use stop in case the leave/open animation is firing when the user exits/enters the element.